# How to make my server public?

Tags: linux, router, virtualbox, apache-http-server, webserver

My computer is running on Windows 8. My web server is running on apache in Lubuntu 13.04 on VirtualBox. [image: apache web server on VirtualBox, Lubuntu 13.04]

I have went to http://www.whatismyip.com and tried going to that IP address on my browser. It sent me to my router's homepage (dd-wrt firmware)

VirtualBox IP address: 10.0.2.15 brings me to the 'It works' page too.

[image: ifconfig]

Tried port forwarding:

[image: portforward]

but it does not work.

If you require more information, please kindly make a comment below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to configure port forwarding on your router to redirect port 80 from the internet to the apache-port in your virtualbox. It seems that your virtualbox network is configured to do network address translation. For the router configuration it would be better if you configure the virtualbox network to bridged mode and assign a IP-Address of your local network, i. e. 192.168.123.17 so you can configure port forwarding as follow in ddwrt:

`80 TCP 192.168.123.17 80`

Bridged mode in virtualbox means that a new virtual network interface is added to your local network and a new IP-Address from that network is assigned, i. e. your local computer has `192.168.123.16` assigned from the routers DHCP-Server so the DHCP-Client in the virtual machine makes a DHCP-Request to the router and the interface gets the IP-Address `192.168.123.17`.

But for clarification:

1. if you don't have any good reason for this I would not recommend publishing a webserver from your local internet access. Maybe you want to try a free [Amazon AWS](http://aws.amazon.com/) instance for this.
2. Having your ddwrt webinterface publicly open is also a bad idea because there are several versions of ddwrt with bugs in the software which enable hackers or other bad people to completely take over your network. And I think maybe the above solution wont work so, because port 80, on which the webinterface of ddwrt runs is occupied. You can disable this by changing the ddwrt in the "Administration" tab and then there are multiple "Remote Access" radio button configuration fields (Web GUI Management, SSH, Telnet). I would recommend to disable them all. If you want to configure your ddwrt via remote access I recommend you to configure a VPN.

Maybe this image can give you an overview or you can also google for "nat port forwarding".
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, can you explain further what you meant by 'bridged mode'? What IP address should I use (IP address of local network? You meant the 'inet addr' (refer to my updated post)). How do you make ddwrt interface private? I am trying to experiment on how I can use VirtualBox to host a simple public server.

Comment: In bridged network mode of your virtual machine your local network interface gets a second IP of your network assigned, i. e. if your host has the IP 192.168.123.15 (assigned from your router) virtualbox adds a virtual interface in the same network and the DHCP-Client in the virtual machine asks for a IP in that network. For ddwrt privat inteface configuration go to the administration tab and there are several "Remote Access" configuration radio buttons. I recommend you to disable all. If you want to remote access to your router it's better to configure a VPN in ddwrt.

Comment: I've set up DDNS (no-ip.org), which IP address will it update? My Lubuntu IP address or the router's WAN IP address (the public IP?)?

Comment: The public address

Comment: Will my Lubuntu IP address change if my broadband plan uses dynamic IP? So I have to keep changing the port forwarding configuration? If my Lubuntu's dynamic IP keeps changing, how can I automatically update it to No-IP.org?

Comment: Your broadband internet connection has nothing to do with your virtual machines configuration. DDNS updates your public IP-Address of your router, the port forwarding enables you redirect access from the internet into your virtual machine. But you should configure a fixed IP in the virtual machine. If the IP of your virtual machine changes the port forwarding configuration goes into nowhere.

Comment: Should I enter my public IP address of the router (WAN IP, right?) to go to my website or the IP address of Lubuntu? (I think it should be WAN IP) How do I configure a fixed IP address in my virtual machine? Strangely, but true, going to my WAN IP will not work, if my chrome extension 'ZenMate for Google Chrome™' is enabled.

Comment: Just edited my answer a bit. The public one, but maybe you cannot test this from within your network because of network routing. Fixed IP-Address can be configuried with the Lubuntu Networkmanager or in the services Tab of your router in the DHCP configuration are in the static leases table. For access with activated ZenMate extensions i cannot give you an answer because I dont know how they exactly work (just read something about VPN and so on but thats no enought for me to give an answer).

Comment: Thanks for that info. Now, how can I create multiple IP addresses in Lubuntu? I can't find Lubuntu Network manager too.

Comment: I haven't used the lxde desktop for a while but I think it must be in the panel next to the clock.

Answer (score 0):

Your VM is running on the 10.0.2.XX, which is networked with your PC. You need to go into virtual box, and change your NIC adapter settings from NAT to Bridged Adapter. You'll get an IP on the 255.255.255.0 subnet. ( 192.168.X.XXX )

Comment: Okay, done it... Noticed that I can navigate to my Virtualbox's IP and I received 'It works!' page. My broadband plan is 'Dynamic IP', is there any chance my Virtualbox's IP will change and I have to keep changing the port forwarding configuration?

Comment: You can make your VM's IP static, via your routers settings.